# Firebase for client

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Normally when we use firebase as developers, we use our own firebase developer console by logging in google account.

But what to do when developing an application for a client which uses firebase? For example I have a client who wants an application which will use firebase for saving and retrieving data. As a developer, I have to use my own firebase account and add a database in my firebase and attach that firebase database with the client's application.

Now as the data will grow larger then google deducts money from my account for using firebase database. How can we make possible that the client pay to the google monthly charges for using firebase not the developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier option is you open a Google account for the project and a similar firebase account for it. When you deliver the project to the client, notify about the expected and show him/her how to pay for the service.   In case their project goes beyond limits. This is what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your client to create a firebase account and add your application there.

After doing that the client can give you the developer or any other access they want but all the payments will only be done from the client side

> On the latest version of Firebase (Announced during Google I/O 2016), how do I add other people to my project or app whom I want to collaborate with? I came across IAM roles through Settings > Permissions. Is this the right way? If I add person there and assign a role, say Editor, will he/she be notified about it through email? Will a request be sent or will they be added directly to that role?

1. Select your project in the new Firebase Console
2. In the top left, next to the project name, click the settings/cog wheel icon
3. Click Users and Permissions
4. In the Google Cloud Developer Console click IAM ADD
5. Enter the name/email of the user to add and select the appropriate role (Project -> Owner/Editor/Viewer, etc as per your requirement)
6. Click Add

The added users will get invite to join the project